# Reuse the same function for ItemTemplate and EditTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, detailsview

I am new to ASP.NET. I have this in my DetailsView:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="VendorName">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList id="insertVendorName" datasourceid="VendorSqlDataSource"
            datatextfield="VendorName" DataValueField="VendorID" 
            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("VendorID") %>'
            runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="-1" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList id="updateVendorName" 
        datasourceid="VendorSqlDataSource"  AutoPostBack="true"
        datatextfield="VendorName" DataValueField="VendorID"  
        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("VendorID") %>'     
        runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlVendor_SelectedIndexChanged"  />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This is my code behind for the Edit mode, which will refresh the dropdownlist.

```
protected void ddlVendor_SelectedIndexChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddlVendor = (DropDownList)DetailsView1.FindControl("updateVendorName");
    DropDownList ddlVendorBU = (DropDownList)DetailsView1.FindControl("VendorBUName");

    /*
    if (DetailsView1.CurrentMode != DetailsViewMode.Edit)
    {
        DropDownList ddlVendor = (DropDownList)DetailsView1.FindControl("insertVendorName");
        int VendorID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlVendor.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        DropDownList ddlVendor = (DropDownList)DetailsView1.FindControl("VendorName");
        int VendorID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlVendor.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }
    */

    if (ddlVendorBU != null)
    {
        Response.Write("SelectChanged");
        int VendorID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlVendor.SelectedValue.ToString());
        Response.Write("VendorID: " + VendorID);

        ddlVendorBU.Items.Clear();

        string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT VendorBUID, VendorBUName FROM dbo.MDF_VendorBU WHERE VendorID = @VendorID";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VendorID", VendorID);
        DataSet objDs = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        con.Open();
        dAdapter.Fill(objDs);

        con.Close();

        /*
        if (objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)  
        { 
           ddlVendorBU.DataSource = objDs.Tables[0];
           ddlVendorBU.ItemTextField = "VendorBUName";
           ddlVendorBU.ItemValueField = "VendorBUID";
           ddlVendorBU.DataBind(); 
        } 
        */

        if (objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in objDs.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                ddlVendorBU.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem((dr["VendorBUName"]).ToString(), (dr["VendorBUID"]).ToString() ));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the EditItemTemplate, I have updateVendorName ID for the dropdownlist, and this ddl calls the ddlVendor_SelectedIndexChange to refresh another list.  Now, I want to use the same code to refresh the list, but in InsertItemTemplate.  Because of the dropdownlist ID is different "insertVendorName", how can I use the same ddlVendor_SelectedIndexChange code, but with different ddl ID (insertVendorName) in the Insert Mode?  Please let me know if I am confusing you.

Any suggestions for the better way to do this would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I find your question confusing to read, can you reduce the code in some way and just keep the parts that are directly relevant to your problem?

Comment: Also, I think it's a bad idea to do data retrieval within your ASP forms. Consider writing a class to access the database and pass the data to your code-behind, which can then format it correctly.

Comment: @Mario, Thanks for responding.  I have updated, and hopefully it's more clear now. Let me know if I still confusing you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same function for both DDLs. So you'd have:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="insertVendorName" .... OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlVendor_SelectedIndexChanged" >
```

Now inside the function itself you need to get a reference to the correct DDL, the one that called the function. That's what `sender` is for.

```
DropDownList ddlVendor = (DropDownList)sender;
```

Answer (score 1):

To put it most simply, you should place the code from your event handlers in a seperate function and call it from there. I will give you a skeleton structure:

```
protected void ddlVendor_SelectedIndexChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyFunction(sender);
}


protected void ddlInsertVendorName_SelectedIndexChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyFunction(sender);
}

protected void MyFunction(Object sender)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender //ddl will contain the ID etc...
    //shared logic here

    if(ddl.ID.equals("ddlVendor"))
    {
        //edit mode
    }
    else 
    {
        //insert mode
    }
}
```

This solution is slightly better than System Down's (otherwise good solution) in that if the event logic of one dropdown list would ever need to change, but not the other, you would have to restructure your code.

It would also be even better if the seperate function **only** does the shared logic, and put the context-specific logic in the respective event handlers. This may require you to let the seperate function return something.

Comment: Good solution! I agree that this is better than mine.

Comment: @Mario, I tried, and I think I did it wrong "if (ddlID.Equals("updateVendorName")) { DropDownList ddlVendor = (DropDownList)DetailsView1.FindControl(ddlID); } else { DropDownList ddlVendor = (DropDownList)DetailsView1.FindControl(ddlID); }" .... Then got an error "The name 'ddlVendor' does not exist " at this line here "int VendorID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlVendor.SelectedValue.ToString());" Sorry, comment field doesn't let me format the code. Let me know if I am confusing, I can post another thread using correct format.

Comment: Your code just doesn't make sense since you are doing exactly the same in the if and else branches. You should remove the if to begin with, second if you need the actual dropdown list, pass the `sender` object from the handler into `MyFunction(Object sender)` instead.

Comment: I already removed the IF, so I have the function "protected void refreshDLL(string ddlID)", to call the function and pass the sender (ddl), is this correct "refreshDLL(object sender);"?  Thanks for helping

Comment: I got it to works now. Perfect!. Thank you so much for helping and being patient with newbie! :-)